Ошибка при считывании данных из файла в R
Пытаюсь получить данные из txt файла, но получаю ошибку, так как на определенной строке в первой и в третьей колонке пустые значения:
data <- read.table(file = "pulse.txt", header = TRUE)


Ошибка в scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
= dec,  :   строка 31 не содержит 4 элементов

Вот данные:
CB  EB  CA  EA
68  76  86  64
104 85  76  68
102 90  72  64
87  94  85  80
76  68  74  72
72  80  84  60
66  98  88  78
85  88  80  84
98  72  80  64
82  90  85  74
76  104 80  72
84  80  80  84
92  78  86  66
85  84  80  88
84  100 80  66
72  78  72  90
80  80  86  60
87  78  84  64
84  80  84  68
90  82  88  70
76  98  72  60
100 72  72  60
80  72  80  60
92  68  84  80
88  88  80  68
78  72  76  72
80  80  76  66
66  86  88  70
72  86  80  60
86  80  76  70
    85      56
    80      68
    104     60
    68      60
    82      82
    76      64
    84      60
    82      62
    72      60
    76      60
    100     86
    68      72
    80      64
    72      82
    94      82
    76      60
    88      56
    78      68
    82      68
    68      66

Как в такой ситуации решается проблема?

Попробуйте ответы к этому вопросу посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818988/read-table-with-variable-columns
